# How to find longer Strings from an Array?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to find Longer Strings from this array:

const myArr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seven", "eighth"]

in this array "second","fourth","eighth" has length of 6. I want to return these in an array.

```
const myArr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seven", "eighth"]

function longerStrings(arr) {
    let largeStrings = []
    let longerWord = ''
    for (let name of arr) {
        if (name.length > longerWord.length) {
            longerWord = name
            largeStrings.push(longerWord)
        }
    }
    return largeStrings
}
longerStrings(myArr)
```

**expected output is**: ["second","fourth","eighth"]

but returns =["first","second"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier if you use filter instead:

```
const myArr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seven", "eighth"]
const longest = myArr.reduce((a, b) =>  a.length > b.length ? a : b);
const res = myArr.filter(el => el.length >= longest.length)
console.log(res)
```

That returns:

```
["second","fourth","eighth"]
```

Or, as Sash mentions below, it can be done in a single pass, although the solution is not as readable:

```
let max = 0;
const reducer = myArray.reduce((previous, current) => {
  if (current.length > max) {
    previous = [];
  }
  if (current.length >= max) {
    previous.push(current);
    max = current.length;
  }
  return previous;
}, []);

console.log(reducer);
```

Comment: your answer only for strings with length greater than 5

Comment: You are right, edited.

Comment: While being easier/more readable. This does require an additional pass over the array.

Comment: @SashSinha Added a single pass solution, but you are right, is way less readable.

Answer (score 2):

When a word longer than any found so far is identified, you need to create an entirely new array (discarding any elements it had before in it), and put the new record-setting word in it. You also need to push a name to the array if the name being iterated over isn't record-setting, but is equal to the current record-setter.

```js
const myArr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seven", "eighth"]

function longerStrings(arr) {
  let largeStrings = []
  let longerWord = ''
  for (let name of arr) {
    if (name.length > longerWord.length) {
      longerWord = name
      largeStrings = [name];
    } else if (name.length === longerWord.length) {
      largeStrings.push(name)
    }
  }
  return largeStrings
}
console.log(longerStrings(myArr));
```